# Cascading DropDownList in a DetailsView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, detailsview

I have two dropdown within a DetailsView and I want to work in cascade, the idea is that an area contains various issues and these issues depend on the selected area, but I get the following error:

**Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.**

in the next line:

```xml
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlIssue" runat="server"
    DataTextField="NameIssue" DataValueField="IdIssue"
```

The complete code is:

```xml
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Area" SortExpression="IdArea">
<EditItemTemplate> 
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlArea" runat="server"
      DataSourceID="SqlDataSource145711" DataTextField="NameArea"
      DataValueField="IdArea" AutoPostBack="true"
      AppendDataBoundItems="true" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("IdArea") %>'> 
  </asp:DropDownList>
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource145711" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BaseDatosCJConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT IdArea, NameArea FROM AREA">
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server"
    Text='<%# Bind("IdArea") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Issue">       
<EditItemTemplate>
**<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlIssue" runat="server"
    DataTextField="NameIssue" DataValueField="IdIssue"**
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource22" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("IdIssue") %>'
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server"
  ID="sqlDataSource22"
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BaseDatosCJConnectionString %>"
  SelectCommand="SELECT IdIssue, NameAIssue, IdArea FROM ISSUE"
  FilterExpression="IdArea = '{0}'">
  <FilterParameters>
  <asp:ControlParameter Name="Param" ControlID="ddlArea"
    PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
  </FilterParameters>                       
</asp:SqlDataSource>

</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Can you help with the solution to this error?

I have to do something from the code?

blessings

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want the problematic area to look like this:

```xml
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlIssue" runat="server"
  DataTextField="NameIssue" DataValueField="IdIssue"
  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource22" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("IdIssue") %'>
```

Note that apostrophe `'` goes before the closing paren.